# Bash - replacing small range of lines in a huge text file efficiently

Tags: bash, sed, split

I'm working on a problem where I have to replace a certain range of lines in a huge text file with data from another (smaller, but still large) text file.

Suppose file1 has 10,000 lines, and file2 3,000 lines. I need to perform operations of the type: extract lines 901-970 from file2 and insert those into lines 8701-8770 of file1, replacing what was there before. In the problem I'm working on file1 has 61 million lines, and file2 18 million. I need this operation to be done efficiently because it is performed several times - in the end the whole content of file2 will be somewhere inside file1.

The best solution I've got so far consists of splitting the two files in small files, each having the number of lines of the block that is copied and replaced (70 in the example above). This proved to be much more efficient than a head and tail combination to extract parts of the file, but still it requires touching parts of file1 that are not modified.

I was wondering if there is a awk/grep/sed solution to this. Extracting a part of file2 is not the problem, but I couldn't figure out how to replace a block of lines of file1 without loading the entire file.

Thanks!

Comment: you can partition the file not necessarily to even number of lines.  For example:  File1_1 (1-900), File1_2 (901_970), File1_3 (971_) and similarly  for File2.  Then join the sections.  File1_1, File2_1, File1_3, etc.  If your sections are large it means number of section will be manageable.

Comment: you should make clear if you literally mean to process by line numbers, or if that is just an approximation to show us the scope of the problem but you will really be looking to scan for specific strings to mark where replacements will occur. Good luck

Comment: @karafka that's also a possibility, but since I need to do several replacements throughout the entire file I'd still have a large number of sections. Thanks.

Comment: @shellter my data has only numbers, and the replacements are determined by the line number, but since each number has the same number of bytes I managed to solve the problem marking the sections by bytes rather than by line number. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you'd have to do a random-access type of operation (as distinct from sequential processing) to "avoid touching" the parts of file1 that don't change, and random-access for files is at the character/byte level, not the line level. That is, if the number of *bytes* (as opposed to lines) being replaced in file1 was the same as the number of *bytes* coming from file2, you could do it (with fseek and the like). But it sounds like that is in no way guaranteed?

So you're going to have to do a single-pass over file1 regardless, so the key will be optimizing the processing within the loop (over file1 lines). Consider processing all the pieces of file2 with one pass over file1? (Rather than multiple operations involving both files.)

Comment: Actually the number of bytes being replaced in file1 matches that coming from file2, so I can use a random-access operation as you suggested - I hadn't realised this was a possibility in my problem. I used dd both to extract the blocks from file2 and to replace in file1 - this is about 30% faster than splitting the file as I was doing previously. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @D.Puetzer Cool! It would be interesting to see the full `dd` command you ended up with, and so that others coming to this question in the future could get a jump-start on similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Following Jeff Y's suggestion I used the dd command to do the replacements efficiently at the byte level. I first extract a block from file2 using:

```
dd if="file2" bs="$bperelem" skip="$start_copy" count=1 of="tmp2" 2> /dev/null
```

where `bperelem` is the number of bytes of the block and `start_copy` is the position where it is located. Then I replace this into file1 using the following:

```
dd if="tmp2" bs="$bperelem" skip=0 count=1 seek="$start_replace" of="file1" conv=notrunc 2> /dev/null
```

For my specific problem the variables `start_copy` and `start_replace` are updated inside a while loop.